# Python + Twisted + FtpClient + SOCKS

Tags: python, ftp, twisted, socks

I just started using Twisted. I want to connect to an FTP server and perform some basic operations (use threading if possible). I am using this [example](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/examples/ftpclient.py).

Which does the job quite well. The question is how to add a SOCKS4/5 proxy usage to the code? Can somebody please provide a working example? I have tried this [link](https://github.com/ln5/twisted-socks) too.

But,

```
    # Copyright (c) Twisted Matrix Laboratories.
    # See LICENSE for details.


    """
    An example of using the FTP client
    """

    # Twisted imports
    from twisted.protocols.ftp import FTPClient, FTPFileListProtocol
    from twisted.internet.protocol import Protocol, ClientCreator
    from twisted.python import usage
    from twisted.internet import reactor, endpoints

    # Socks support test
    from socksclient import SOCKSv4ClientProtocol, SOCKSWrapper
    from twisted.web import client

    # Standard library imports
    import string
    import sys
    try:
        from cStringIO import StringIO
    except ImportError:
        from StringIO import StringIO


    class BufferingProtocol(Protocol):
        """Simple utility class that holds all data written to it in a buffer."""
        def __init__(self):
            self.buffer = StringIO()

        def dataReceived(self, data):
            self.buffer.write(data)

    # Define some callbacks

    def success(response):
        print 'Success!  Got response:'
        print '---'
        if response is None:
            print None
        else:
            print string.join(response, '\n')
        print '---'


    def fail(error):
        print 'Failed.  Error was:'
        print error

    def showFiles(result, fileListProtocol):
        print 'Processed file listing:'
        for file in fileListProtocol.files:
            print '    %s: %d bytes, %s' \
                  % (file['filename'], file['size'], file['date'])
        print 'Total: %d files' % (len(fileListProtocol.files))

    def showBuffer(result, bufferProtocol):
        print 'Got data:'
        print bufferProtocol.buffer.getvalue()


    class Options(usage.Options):
        optParameters = [['host', 'h', 'example.com'],
                         ['port', 'p', 21],
                         ['username', 'u', 'webmaster'],
                         ['password', None, 'justapass'],
                         ['passive', None, 0],
                         ['debug', 'd', 1],
                        ]

    # Socks support                    
    def wrappercb(proxy):
        print "connected to proxy", proxy
        pass

    def run():
        def sockswrapper(proxy, url):
            dest = client._parse(url) # scheme, host, port, path
            endpoint = endpoints.TCP4ClientEndpoint(reactor, dest[1], dest[2])
            return SOCKSWrapper(reactor, proxy[1], proxy[2], endpoint)

        # Get config
        config = Options()
        config.parseOptions()
        config.opts['port'] = int(config.opts['port'])
        config.opts['passive'] = int(config.opts['passive'])
        config.opts['debug'] = int(config.opts['debug'])

        # Create the client
        FTPClient.debug = config.opts['debug']
        creator = ClientCreator(reactor, FTPClient, config.opts['username'],
                                config.opts['password'], passive=config.opts['passive'])
        #creator.connectTCP(config.opts['host'], config.opts['port']).addCallback(connectionMade).addErrback(connectionFailed)

        # Socks support
        proxy = (None, '1.1.1.1', 1111, True, None, None)
        sw = sockswrapper(proxy, "ftp://example.com")
        d = sw.connect(creator)
        d.addCallback(wrappercb)

        reactor.run()

    def connectionFailed(f):
        print "Connection Failed:", f
        reactor.stop()

    def connectionMade(ftpClient):
        # Get the current working directory
        ftpClient.pwd().addCallbacks(success, fail)

        # Get a detailed listing of the current directory
        fileList = FTPFileListProtocol()
        d = ftpClient.list('.', fileList)
        d.addCallbacks(showFiles, fail, callbackArgs=(fileList,))

        # Change to the parent directory
        ftpClient.cdup().addCallbacks(success, fail)

        # Create a buffer
        proto = BufferingProtocol()

        # Get short listing of current directory, and quit when done
        d = ftpClient.nlst('.', proto)
        d.addCallbacks(showBuffer, fail, callbackArgs=(proto,))
        d.addCallback(lambda result: reactor.stop())


    # this only runs if the module was *not* imported
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        run()
```

I know the code is wrong. I need Solution.

Comment: FTP is a complicated (read: bad) protocol, and some points of clarification are sort of required before proceeding.  First: do you need to support active transfers or will PASV transfers be sufficient?  Second: does it have to use twisted?  Python ships with an ftplib which can be extended to support socks.  Third: is your socks proxy behind a VIP or just a single host directly connected to the Internet?

Comment: 1. Any type of transfers will do.

Comment: 2. It needs multithreading with different SOCKS. Any thoughts on how to use ftplib with different socks for a connection are welcome.

Comment: 3. Just a regular proxy.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, so here's a solution ([gist](https://gist.github.com/4409975)) that uses python's built-in [`ftplib`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ftplib.html), as well as the open source [`SocksiPy` module](https://github.com/mikedougherty/SocksiPy).

It doesn't use twisted, and it doesn't explicitly use threads, but using and communicting between threads is pretty easily done with `threading.Thread` and `threading.Queue` in [python's standard `threading` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html)

Basically, we need to subclass ftplib.FTP to support substituting our own `create_connection` method and add proxy configuration semantics.

The "main" logic just configures an FTP client that connects via a localhost socks proxy, such as one created by `ssh -D localhost:1080 socksproxy.example.com`, and downloads a source snapshot for GNU autoconf to the local disk.

```
import ftplib
import socket
import socks  # socksipy (https://github.com/mikedougherty/SocksiPy)


class FTP(ftplib.FTP):
    def __init__(self, host='', user='', passwd='', acct='',
                 timeout=socket._GLOBAL_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT,
                 proxyconfig=None):
        """Like ftplib.FTP constructor, but with an added `proxyconfig` kwarg

        `proxyconfig` should be a dictionary that may contain the following
        keys:

        proxytype - The type of the proxy to be used. Three types
                are supported: PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS4 (including socks4a),
                PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5 and PROXY_TYPE_HTTP
        addr -      The address of the server (IP or DNS).
        port -      The port of the server. Defaults to 1080 for SOCKS
                servers and 8080 for HTTP proxy servers.
        rdns -      Should DNS queries be preformed on the remote side
                (rather than the local side). The default is True.
                Note: This has no effect with SOCKS4 servers.
        username -  Username to authenticate with to the server.
                The default is no authentication.
        password -  Password to authenticate with to the server.
                Only relevant when username is also provided.
        """
        self.proxyconfig = proxyconfig or {}
        ftplib.FTP.__init__(self, host, user, passwd, acct, timeout)

    def connect(self, host='', port=0, timeout=-999):
        '''Connect to host.  Arguments are:
         - host: hostname to connect to (string, default previous host)
         - port: port to connect to (integer, default previous port)
        '''
        if host != '':
            self.host = host
        if port > 0:
            self.port = port
        if timeout != -999:
            self.timeout = timeout
        self.sock = self.create_connection(self.host, self.port)
        self.af = self.sock.family
        self.file = self.sock.makefile('rb')
        self.welcome = self.getresp()
        return self.welcome

    def create_connection(self, host=None, port=None):
        host, port = host or self.host, port or self.port
        if self.proxyconfig:

            phost, pport = self.proxyconfig['addr'], self.proxyconfig['port']
            err = None
            for res in socket.getaddrinfo(phost, pport, 0, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
                af, socktype, proto, canonname, sa = res
                sock = None
                try:
                    sock = socks.socksocket(af, socktype, proto)
                    sock.setproxy(**self.proxyconfig)

                    if self.timeout is not socket._GLOBAL_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT:
                        sock.settimeout(self.timeout)
                    sock.connect((host, port))
                    return sock

                except socket.error as _:
                    err = _
                    if sock is not None:
                        sock.close()

            if err is not None:
                raise err
            else:
                raise socket.error("getaddrinfo returns an empty list")
        else:
            sock = socket.create_connection((host, port), self.timeout)
        return sock

    def ntransfercmd(self, cmd, rest=None):
        size = None
        if self.passiveserver:
            host, port = self.makepasv()
            conn = self.create_connection(host, port)
            try:
                if rest is not None:
                    self.sendcmd("REST %s" % rest)
                resp = self.sendcmd(cmd)
                # Some servers apparently send a 200 reply to
                # a LIST or STOR command, before the 150 reply
                # (and way before the 226 reply). This seems to
                # be in violation of the protocol (which only allows
                # 1xx or error messages for LIST), so we just discard
                # this response.
                if resp[0] == '2':
                    resp = self.getresp()
                if resp[0] != '1':
                    raise ftplib.error_reply, resp
            except:
                conn.close()
                raise
        else:
            raise Exception("Active transfers not supported")
        if resp[:3] == '150':
            # this is conditional in case we received a 125
            size = ftplib.parse150(resp)
        return conn, size


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ftp = FTP(host='ftp.gnu.org', user='anonymous', passwd='guest',
              proxyconfig=dict(proxytype=socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, rdns=False,
                               addr='localhost', port=1080))
    with open('autoconf-2.69.tar.xz', mode='w') as f:
        ftp.retrbinary("RETR /gnu/autoconf/autoconf-2.69.tar.xz", f.write)
```

To elaborate why I asked some of my original questions:

1) Do you need to support active transfers or will PASV transfers be sufficient?

Active transfers are much harder to do via a socks proxy because they require the use of the PORT command.  With the PORT command, your ftp client tells the FTP server to connect to *you* on a specific port (e.g., on your PC) in order to send the data.  This is likely to not work for users behind a firewall or NAT/router.  If your SOCKS proxy server is *not* behind a firewall, or has a public IP, it is possible to support active transfers, but it is complicated:  It requires your SOCKS server (ssh -D does support this) and client library (socksipy does not) to support remote port binding.  It also requires the appropriate hooks in the application (my example throws an exception if `passiveserver = False`) to do a remote BIND instead of a local one.

2) Does it have to use twisted?

Twisted is great, but I'm not the best at it, and I haven't found a really great SOCKS client implementation.  Ideally there would be a library out there that allowed you to define and/or chain proxies together, returning an object that implements the [IReactorTCP](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/8.2.0/api/twisted.internet.interfaces.IReactorTCP.html) interface, but I have not yet found anything like this just yet.

3) Is your socks proxy behind a VIP or just a single host directly connected to the Internet?

This matters because of the way PASV transfer security works.  In a PASV transfer, the client asks the server to provide a port to connect in order to start a data transfer.  When the server accepts a connection on that port, it SHOULD verify the client is connected *from the same source IP* as the connection that requested the transfer.  If your SOCKS server is behind a VIP, it is less likely that the outbound IP of the connection made for the PASV transfers will match the outbound IP of the primary communication connection.